# Bash script checking cpu usage of specific process

Tags: bash, integer, arithmetic-expressions

First off, I'm new to this. I have some experience with windows scripting and apple script but not much with bash. What I'm trying to do is grab the PID and %CPU of a specific process. then compare the %CPU against a set number, and if it's higher, kill the process. I feel like I'm close, but now I'm getting the following error:

[[: 0.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")

what am I doing wrong? here's my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i app_pid
declare -i app_cpu
declare -i cpu_limit
app_name="top"
cpu_limit="50"
app_pid=`ps aux | grep $app_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}`
app_cpu=`ps aux | grep $app_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $3'}`
if [[ ! $app_cpu -gt $cpu_limit ]]; then
     echo "crap"
else
     echo "we're good"
fi
```

Obviously I'm going to replace the echos in the if/then statement but it's acting as if the statement is true regardless of what the cpu load actually is (I tested this by changing the -gt to -lt and it still echoed "crap"

Thank you for all the help. Oh, and this is on a OS X 10.7 if that is important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that bash can't handle decimals. You can just multiply them by 100 and work with plain integers instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i app_pid
declare -i app_cpu
declare -i cpu_limit
app_name="top"
cpu_limit="5000"
app_pid=`ps aux | grep $app_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}`
app_cpu=`ps aux | grep $app_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $3*100'}`
if [[ $app_cpu -gt $cpu_limit ]]; then
     echo "crap"
else
     echo "we're good"
fi
```

Keep in mind that CPU percentage is a suboptimal measurement of application health. If you have two processes running infinite loops on a single core system, no other application of the same priority will ever go over 33%, even if they're trashing around.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!

as for the %CPU, we actually have a process that starts eating CPU, get's to 100-200% and it then prevents the user from signing into the computer, killing the process causes it to restart and sit at .1% for a long time.

I plan on having this run this as a Launch Daemon "on demand" so it should kill the process, so users don't have to reboot 1/3-1/2 the time the screen locks.

Comment: What if there are multiple processes with the same name and I just need to find the one which is above the set CPU?

Comment: `./killJava.sh: line 7: 2941
8715: syntax error in expression (error token is "8715")
./killJava.sh: line 8: 10
60: syntax error in expression (error token is "60")`

What are these errors?

Comment: @SandeepC It means there are multiple processes, which the original script did not account for

Comment: To do something for each item in a list, use a loop

Answer (score 12):

I recommend taking a look at the facilities of `ps` to avoid multiple horrible things you do.

On my system (`ps` from procps on linux, GNU awk) I would do this:

```
ps -C "$app-name" -o pid=,pcpu= | 
    awk --assign maxcpu="$cpu_limit" '$2>maxcpu {print "crappy pid",$1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh
PROCESS="java"
PID=`pgrep $PROCESS | tail -n 1`
CPU=`top -b -p $PID -n 1 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $9}'`
echo $CPU
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `top` to check some details. It provides a few more details like CPU time.

On Linux this would be:

```
top -b -n 1  | grep $app_name
```

On Mac, with its BSD version of top:

```
top -l 1  | grep $app_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, using top and bc.

Use it by passing in ex: `./script apache2 50 # max 50%`

If there are many PIDs matching your program argument, only one will be calculated, based on how top lists them. I could have extended the script by catching them all and avergaing the percentage or something, but this will have to do.

You can also pass in a number, `./script.sh 12345 50`, which will force it to use an exact PID.

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1: ['command\ name' or PID number(,s)] 2: MAX_CPU_PERCENT

[[ $# -ne 2 ]] && exit 1
PID_NAMES=$1
# get all PIDS as nn,nn,nn
if [[ ! "$PID_NAMES" =~ ^[0-9,]+$ ]] ; then
    PIDS=$(pgrep -d ',' -x $PID_NAMES)
else
    PIDS=$PID_NAMES
fi
#  echo "$PIDS $MAX_CPU"
MAX_CPU="$2"
MAX_CPU="$(echo "($MAX_CPU+0.5)/1" | bc)"
LOOP=1
while [[ $LOOP -eq 1 ]] ; do
    sleep 0.3s
    # Depending on your 'top' version and OS you might have
    #   to change head and tail line-numbers
    LINE="$(top -b -d 0 -n 1 -p $PIDS | head -n 8 \
        | tail -n 1 | sed -r 's/[ ]+/,/g' | \
        sed -r 's/^\,|\,$//')"
    # If multiple processes in $PIDS, $LINE will only match\
    #   the most active process
    CURR_PID=$(echo "$LINE" | cut -d ',' -f 1)
    # calculate cpu limits
    CURR_CPU_FLOAT=$(echo "$LINE"| cut -d ',' -f 9)
    CURR_CPU=$(echo "($CURR_CPU_FLOAT+0.5)/1" | bc)
    echo "PID $CURR_PID: $CURR_CPU""%"
    if [[ $CURR_CPU -ge $MAX_CPU ]] ; then
        echo "PID $CURR_PID ($PID_NAMES) went over $MAX_CPU""%"
        echo "[[ $CURR_CPU""% -ge $MAX_CPU""% ]]"
        LOOP=0
        break
    fi
done
echo "Stopped"
```

Answer (score 0):

Erik, I used a modified version of your code to create a new script that does something similar. Hope you don't mind it.

A bash script to get the CPU usage by process
usage:

```
nohup ./check_proc bwengine 70 &
```

`bwegnine` is the process name we want to monitor 70 is to log only when the process is using over 70% of the CPU.

Check the logs at: `/var/log/check_procs.log`

The output should be like:

```
DATE | TOTAL CPU | CPU USAGE | Process details
```

Example:

```
03/12/14 17:11 |20.99|98| ProdPROXY-ProdProxyPA.tra

03/12/14 17:11 |20.99|100| ProdPROXY-ProdProxyPA.tra
```

Link to the full blog:
http://felipeferreira.net/?p=1453

Answer (score 0):

It is also useful to have `app_user` information available to test whether the current user has the rights to kill/modify the running process. This information can be obtained along with the needed `app_pid` and `app_cpu` by using `read` eliminating the need for `awk` or any other 3rd party parser:

```
read app_user app_pid tmp_cpu stuff <<< \
$( ps aux | grep "$app_name" | grep -v "grep\|defunct\|${0##*/}" )
```

You can then get your `app_cpu * 100` with:

```
app_cpu=$((${tmp_cpu%.*} * 100))
```

**Note:** Including `defunct` and `${0##*/}` in `grep -v` prevents against multiple processes matching `$app_name`.